# Celerity - Help with popup_browser select list that updates div text on main browser

Tags: screen-scraping, celerity

I'm screen scraping a page that includes a link that spawns a popup window that is comprised of a select list and a button to execute your selection.  The objective is to click the link on the main page, make a selection on the pop-up window, click the link to confirm the selection and then view the new selection on the main webpage.

Here are the steps that I'm taking in Celerity and the results:

```
popup_browser = browser.image(:alt, 'Holidays').click_and_attach
#this creates a new browser to deal with the popup window
popup_browser.select_list(:id, 'ddlSlot1').select_value('Christmas')
#Selecting Christmas from the select list
popup_browser.link(:id, 'btnChangeHoliday').click
#Confirms/Implements selection
popup_browser.close
#Closes popup browser
puts browser.div(:id, 'HolidayName').text
#Here I try to print the updated holiday but nothing is printed (no text value)
```

Everything seems to work fine except for the last line. I've done some debugging and have confirmed that my selection has been made.  It seems that the main webpage is not being updated after I click the ChangeHoliday button on the popup page.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an easy fix.  The only change required for the script to work is to add the resynchronize option to the browser initialization.  After doing so the script works as expected.

```
browser = Celerity::IE.new(:resynchronize => true)
```